# Bootstrap Collapse missed event when mousing through quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

I have run into a problem when using bootstraps collapse and a hover event. There is small delay (not sure if this is supposed to happen) and if you mouse out before the delay is complete then the mouse out is not caught. You can do the same thing with mousing out and back in before the delay.

I have created a js-fiddle example of what is happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/3g2gdyn4/4/

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_area">
        </div>
        <div class="box_dropdown">
           <ul>
               <li>Test</li>
           </ul>
        </div
    </div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box_area").hover(function(e) {
        $(".box_dropdown").collapse("show")
    }, function(e) {
        $(".box_dropdown").collapse("hide")
    });
})

.box_area {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.box_dropdown {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

Frameworks and Extensions:

- //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

External Refrences:

- //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
- //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

I have tried  .show and .hide instead of .collapse but I run into a different bug when sized for phones. So this is not an option unless I can solve that bug. However it is a lot harder to show example because it only shows up for touch screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/press/k4tgphh2/)**

I changed the way your javascript functions. Instead of triggering the `.collapse()` plugin from Bootstrap we're triggering the toggling of the `in` class. The effect is the same, and is something Bootstrap uses for their collapse system, but we just go about it from a different way in this situation.

You'll have to full screen the snippet to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box_area").hover(function(e) {
        $('.box_dropdown').toggleClass('in');
    }, function(e) {
        $('.box_dropdown').toggleClass('in');
    });
})
```

```css
.box_area {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.box_dropdown {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_area">
        </div>
        <div class="box_dropdown collapse">
            <ul>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This takes me back to my other bug but it does correct what I asked about in this question. Thank you.

Comment: @nejohannsen ah sorry about that. But at least I could help in some way!